# DOMPDF: How to customize the name of the single pdf, relating to a single client, with the information present in the object

Tags: laravel, dompdf, laravel-9, laravel-dompdf

I am trying to create the pdf, using the domPDF library, for each single client present in the table of my application. So far everything ok!

When I go to save the pdf I want the name of the pdf document to be saved as:

**name_client_surname_client.pdf**,

so if for example I have a client named **Alex Haiold**, the document must be saved as **Alex_Haiold.pdf**

To do this, since I am passing the single client in the controller, as shown below, I tried to write

> ***return $pdf->download('client->surname client->name.pdf');***

but it is saved as

**client-_surname client-_name.pdf** (then printing client-_surname client-_name).

Here my code:

```
    public function generatePDF(Client $client)
    {
  
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Welcome to LaravelTuts.com',
            'date' => date('m/d/Y'),
            'client' => $client
        ]; 
            
        //dd($data);
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('client.clientPDF', $data);
     
        return $pdf->download('client->surname client->name.pdf');
    }
```

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: `$pdf->download('client->surname client->name.pdf')` contains a string without variables - `$pdf->download($client->surname . ' ' .  $client->name . '.pdf')` contains a string **with** variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('client.clientPDF', $data);
return $pdf->download($client->surname . ' ' . client->name . '.pdf');
```

On the first line, we are just making a view file. The file is `resources/views/client.clientPDF.blade.php` and we are feeding data to the view file by passing the variable `$data` to it.

After making the view, our next step is to download the pdf file. For doing this, we need to call the `download` method of the instance.

On the first parameter, we are passing the filename with extension(pdf).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Yeah. Already added some explanation. Thanks for your suggestion.